# Can't load static files Django 1.9

Tags: django

Template cant find static files and load it on page. 
This is my settings:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'cargo/templates')
# STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'cargo/static')

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = 'os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"),       "domains/h2h.su/static/")'
```

This my path to files cargo/static/cargo/images and templates at the same path in cargo app cargo/templates/cargo/index.html

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you screenshot your file structure?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem by changing `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),`
to `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "cargo"),`